# test coverage nose vs pytest

Tags: python, code-coverage, nose, pytest

I have a lib with folder1 and folder 2 in it. These folders also have sub-folders in them. When I used nose to do tests, I used the following arguments:

```
noseargs = "--verbose -w test --with-coverage --cover-package folder1,folder2"
```

with pytest, I am using this:

```
testargs = "--cov folder1 --cov folder2"
```

I am getting significant differences in my test coverage reports. Nose reported about 85% coverage, while pytest reports only 45%

Is it normal to have such a wide discrepancy in results?

Comment: Have you tried splitting the pytest command (pytest --cov folder1, pytest --cov folder2)? May pytest doesn't expect 2 folders.

Comment: The best clue as to what's going on is in the full coverage report, which will show what modules have what coverage numbers.  Comparing them  from the two test runners will show where the discrepancy is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that a few tests were using setup and teardown but the classes were not inheriting from unittest.TestCase. pytest was skipping these tests.